# How to fill audit fields that are in Audit extendable entity mapped super class?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers, auditing, spring-data-envers

I'm using hibernate envers to audit my entities.
I have OfficeEntity like this:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
@Table(name = "office")
@AuditTable("office_aud")
public class OfficeEntity extends Auditable{

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name = "office_id")
      private Long id;

      @Column(name = "office_code")
      private String officeCode;

      @Column(name = "office_name")
      private String OfficeName;

      //getters & setters & constructor 
}
```

and Auditable entity like this :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Auditable{

      @CreatedBy
      @Column(name = "created_by")
      private String createdBy;

      @CreatedDate
      @Column(name = "created_date")
      private Date createdDate;

      @LastModifiedBy
      @Column(name = "last_modified_by")
      private String lastModifiedBy;

      @LastModifiedDate
      @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
      private Date lastModifiedDate;

      //getters & setters & constructor
}
```

It seems with this structure audit fields does not fill in office_aud table.
So anybody knows how can i fill audit fields in office_aud table??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found annotation in hibernate envers that solved this problem.
So you can add:

```
@AuditOverride(forClass = Auditable.class)
```

to the child entity class and audit fields will be set.
Child entity will be like this:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "office")
@AuditOverride(forClass = Auditable.class)
@AuditTable("office_aud")
public class OfficeEntity extends Auditable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "office_id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "office_code")
  private String officeCode;

  @Column(name = "office_name")
  private String OfficeName;

  //getters & setters & constructor
```

}